# X-Wing 'Overlapping' ships question

Tags: star-wars-x-wing

Let's say that a TIE fighter moves first and his final position causes an overlap with a X-wing fighter. Then the X-wing fighter moves and in its final position is no longer touching that of the overlapping TIE fighter's first move.

Is this still considered an overlap for the TIE fighter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**, this is an overlap.  Each ships move is completed in order without regard to what other ships *may* do in the future.

If the TIE fighter overlaps the X-Wing follow the procedure on page 17 of [the rules](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/ffg_content/x-wing/support/SWX01_XwingCoreRulebook_lowres.pdf) to resolve the overlap before moving on to the X-Wing's move.

Reminder - the TIE fighter loses his *Perform Action* step as a penalty for causing the overlap.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply, I will head on over to the rules and read on. To clarify, he will lose his 'Perform Action' but what about his 'Free Action.' Maybe the rules will clear that up, also.

Comment: The TIE Fighter will skip it's 'Perform Action' step due to the overlap when resolving its movement, so anything that would rely on that specific action would also be skipped. However, most free actions have other triggers (e.g. Squad Leader causes another friendly ship to immediately perform a free action, completely outside of their Perform Action step).

Comment: I see. I read through a lot of the rules provided in the link by Pat Ludwig, also, and your comment, David, also seems to fall in line with that. Thank you.